# Always asked for forms credentials when opening asp.net site from powerpoint hyperlink

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication, powerpoint

Fairly straightforward issue - i put a hyperlink to an asp.net website with forms auth into powerpoint. Click on the link, it asks me for my uname/pwd. i put it in, say 'remember me next time', close browser, click on link in powerpoint again, login page comes up again.

If i simply open the browser and go to the site, it doesn't ask me for my credentials. it knows i've asked it to remember them. It's like the powerpoint click somehow disables cookies on first visit?

Any ideas?

**EDIT**: I can also confirm this action happens in word, but not in outlook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's because powerpoint tries to open the file first, doesn't have the cookies of the web browser, gets a password/login page, **then** redirects that to a web browser.

There is a registry fix. See below:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/899927

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/218153